# Can somebody explain this `ln -s` command to me?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, symbolic-link

The command in question is:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/foo.so /usr/lib/
```

I read [this article](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ln.htm) about `ln`, which indicates that the latter argument can be either a name or a directory. In this case, with it being a directory, my assumption is that the above command causes access to `/usr/lib/foo.so` to be directed to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/foo.so`. If that's true, what is the value in omitting the name in the latter argument vs explicitly including the name (e.g., `/usr/lib/foo.so`)? Is this just a common shortcut, or is there a value in doing this? Also, does creating the symbolic link in this way have any other effect that it wouldn't if the name was included in the latter argument?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose of omitting the name is that you will save time typing, considering that you may have multiple targets specified. See the [manual](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ln&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=Debian%205.0%20lenny&format=html&locale=en).

> ln [OPTION]... TARGET... DIRECTORY     (3rd form)
>
> In the 3rd  and  4th  forms, create links to each TARGET in DIRECTORY

Comment: The value is in being able to create a ton of differently named links in the same directory.

Comment: @DanielBeck - does this mean that I can use `ln -s /usr/bin/foo1.so /usr/bin/foo2.so /usr/bin` and it will link both `foo1.so` and `foo2.so`? The use of simply `TARGET` in the man page makes me think I can only provide one target at a time.

Comment: @orokusaki Yes. That's what the `...` means.

Comment: Well you asked `what is the value in omitting the name...`.

Comment: Oh snap, I misunderstood you. Hahah, I get it now. Hopefully you do too?

Comment: @Goran_Mandic - I do now, thanks. When I read your answer though, I was like :/ eh? If you can update it, and I'll accept it.

Comment: @DanielBeck - ah, thanks (re: your `...` comment).